# extending default iOS phone number/address detection actions

Tags: ios

When you have a text area in iOS, it has the capability to detect phone numbers, URLs, and street addresses.  When you touch and hold on the linked item, it will pop up actions.

For example, when you see a phone number such as 303-338-2929 and tap and hold the link you will see the following options:

Call, Text Message, Create New Contact, Add to Existing contact.

Is there any way to extend these default actions for my own app?  For example, web search.

thanks for any ideas....

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the "Advanced Text Processing" talk from WWDC 2011 useful. [[video](https://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.8270634034.08270634040.8367260939?i=1082810978), [slides]](http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/128_advancedtextprocessing.pdf)